# bash to store unique value if array in variable

Tags: bash

The `bash` below goes to a folder and stores all the unique values that are `.html` file names in `f1`. It then removes all text after the `_` in `$p`. I added a `for` loop to get the unique id in `$p`. The terminal out shows `$p` is correct, but the last value is only being stored in the new array ($sorted_unique_ids), I am not sure why all three are not.

```
dir=/path/to
  var=$(ls -td "$dir"/*/ | head -1)  ## sore newest <run> in var
for f1 in "$var"/qc/*.html ; do 
# Grab file prefix
  bname=`basename $f1` # strip of path
  p="$(echo $bname|cut -d_ -f1)"
    typeset -A myarray  ## define associative array
    myarray[${p}]=yes  ## store p in myarray
     for i in ${!myarray[@]}; do echo ${!myarray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort; done
done
```

**output**

```
id1
id1
id1
id2
id1
id2
id1
id2
id3
id1
id2
id3
```

**desired sorted_unique_ids**

```
id1
id2
id3
```

Comment: Then why do you loop through a single element `"$p"`?

Comment: I change it to `"${id[@]}"` with the same result. Thank you :).

Comment: `$p` is not an array here, neither is `$id`, so it makes no sense to use the `${var[@]}` syntax.

Comment: Please post example directory structure. I am very not sure what exactly you want to do. Do you have files like `"$var"/qc/id1_blabla.html` `"$var"/qc/id2_blabla.html` `"$var"/qc/id3_blabla.html`? And you want to get the list of ids? Then why do you run `for i in ${!myarray[@]}` for _each file_?

Comment: re: the latest edit ... move the line ... ` for i in ${!myarray[@]}; do echo ${!myarray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort; done` down in your script, past the last `done`; right now you're getting repeated lines on output because you are, basically, printing each `p` value to stdout as you process it ... where what you want to do is wait until you've completed all loop processing, completed all array assignments, and **then** you should find that you have a unique set of `p` values stored in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
dir=$(ls -td "$dir"/*/ | head -1)
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*_*.html' -printf "%f\n" |
cut -d_ -f1 | sort -u
```

For input directory structure created like:

```
dir=dir
mkdir -p dir/dir
touch dir/dir/id{1,2,3}_{a,b,c}.html
```

So it looks like this:

```
dir/dir/id2_b.html
dir/dir/id1_c.html
dir/dir/id2_c.html
dir/dir/id1_b.html
dir/dir/id3_b.html
dir/dir/id2_a.html
dir/dir/id3_a.html
dir/dir/id1_a.html
dir/dir/id3_c.html
```

The script will output:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/JuvenileRoundDistributedcomputing).

Answer (score 1):

Define an associative array:

```
typeset -A myarray
```

Use each `p` value as the index for an array element; assign any value you want to the array element (the value just acts as a placeholder):

```
myarray[${p}]=yes
```

If you run across the same `p` value more than once, each assignment to the array will overwrite the previous assignment; net result is that you'll only ever have a single element in the array with a value of `p`.

To obtain your unique list of `p` values, you can loop through the indexes for the array, eg:

```
for i in ${!myarray[@]}
do
    echo ${i}
done
```

If you need the array indexes generated in sorted order try:

```
echo ${!myarray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
```

You can then use this sorted result set as needed (eg, dump to stdout, feed to a loop, etc).

---

So, adding my code to the OPs original code would give us:

```
typeset -A myarray  ## define associative array

dir=/path/to
var=$(ls -td "$dir"/*/ | head -1)  ## sore newest <run> in var
for f1 in "$var"/qc/*.html ; do 
  # Grab file prefix
  bname=`basename $f1` # strip of path
  p="$(echo $bname|cut -d_ -f1)"
  myarray[${p}]=yes  ## store p in myarray
done

# display sorted, unique set of p values
for i in ${!myarray[@]}; do echo ${!myarray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort; done
```

Comment: I added the output in the edit of the post, the lines are repeating :).

Comment: you populate the array inside your loop; *after* you've completed all of your looping (and array assigments) *then* you add my processing; you're getting repeated lines of output because you're, basically, just printing each `p` value to stdout as you process it

Comment: I've updated the answer to show proper use of the `typeset` and display of the final array indexes

Comment: I think the usage of associative array is just questionable. Why not a single array like, and instead of `myarray[${p}]=yes` just add the element `myarray+=("$p")`? What for is that `yes`?

Comment: 'yes' ==> `acts as a placeholder` ... need to assign *something* to the array, right?  and I'm not sure your proposal works ... would need to see your complete solution

Answer (score 1):

```
latest=`ls -t "$dir"|head -1`    # or …|sed q` if you're really jonesing for keystrokes
for f in "$latest"/qc/*_*.html; do f=${f##*/}; printf %s\\n "${f%_*}"; done | sort -u
```